# How do I cite a figure from a journal paper?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I'm trying to create a BibTeX citation for a taxonomic illustration (to add the work to my ORCID, if it matters), but I can't seem to figure out what tags are appropriate here. For reference, the full-text citation (I'm using the journal *Ecology*'s citation format) would be something like this:

Author, B.B. *Phyton novum*. [Illustration] In Author, A.A. (2000). New species of *Phyton* from Mars. *Novon: A Journal for Botanical Nomenclature* 1(100): 5.

I get how to format the citation for the article itself:

```
@article{Author_2000,
  year=2000, month={jan}, volume = {1}, number = {100}, pages = {5},
  author = {Alice A. Author},
  title = {New species of \textit{Phyton} from Mars},
  journal = {Novon: A Journal for Botanical Nomenclature},
  publisher = {Missouri Botanical Garden Press}}
```

How should I modify that, though, when the work being cited is a *figure within* that article? I'd use `inbook` or `incollection`, but the parent work is a journal article rather than a book.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please tell us which bibliography style you use. Please also tell us if you use a citation management package, say, `cite` or `natbib`.

Comment: Do you means something like this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159460/124842

Comment: Is the author of the article the author of the figure? If so, you don't really need a different source: just the article. If the figure has a different author, though, things are trickier and the answer below won't work.

Comment: @cfr if the figure has a different author, then I'd use `@MISC` with `howpublished={Reproduced in \cite[Figure~4]{article}}`.  This will require two bibtex runs, of course.

Comment: The figure does indeed have a different author. Thanks for the answers -- I'll try these and find out!

Answer (score 7):

The usual way is `\cite[Figure~5]{Author_2000}`.  Conceptually it is the same as `\cite[Chapter~2]{Book}` or `\cite[p.~4]{Article}`.  You do not create a new reference, you pin your reference to a specific place in the source.

**UPDATE**

Looks like OP wanted to have a separate citation for a figure with the author different from the book author.  Ok, here is how to do this:

```
@Misc{VitruvianMan,
  author =   {da Vinci, Leonardo},
  title =    {Vitruvian man},
  howpublished = {Reproduced as Figure~5 in \cite{LifeOfLeonardo}},
  year =     1490}


@Article{LifeOfLeonardo,
  author =   {A. U. Thor},
  title =    {Life of {L}eonardo},
  journal =      {Art Studies},
  year =     2017,
  volume =   1,
  number =   2,
  pages =    {35--28}}
```

Comment: As I understand it, the OP is asking how to reference the figure in the bibliography, not how to cite it in the text.

Comment: Sverre is right.