# How do you cite a picture (using biblatex)?

Tags: biblatex

For the project I am working on, I am inserting a couple of pictures that I have to cite. What would be the best way to do that? I am thinking of either putting the citation right below the pictures graphic, or perhaps only citing the picture at the end of the document. (Maybe using `\listoffigures`?)

How do I cite the source for a certain image?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "cite a picture"? Do you mean refer to it in the text, in which case you can use `figure`, `\label` and `\ref`, or cite the source of the picture, in which you may just add `\caption{... From \cite{...}.}`.

Comment: @marmot I thnik the OP want to cite it in bibtex or biblatex that means that he/she want to find out what entry is appropriate to give the information needed in reference.. ie, `@article`, or simmilar entry. The question is realated to this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159446/120578 and have been answered... Possible duplicate

Comment: list of figures will show the title of the figure in a list... If the rights of the picture are not yours and you have to respect some rules (like citing everything external) use a citation (and may be a note or a footnote in its caption)

Comment: Sorry, to precise my question: I mean I want to give the source of a certain image. How would you do that?

Comment: Please see the linked question (related above in my comment)

Comment: I think marmots comment might be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this. The most straightforward way in my view would be to simply `\cite` the source in the `\caption`. I'd also use the optional argument to avoid the citation being repeated unnecessarily in the `\listoffigures`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption[A duck]{A duck \parencite{sigfridsson}}
\end{figure}
Lorem ipsum
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The image of a duck with a pizza and rabbit's ears. The caption reads: "Figure 1: A duck (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998)"]

Do keep in mind that certain licences may require you to show more than just a citation label next to the work (CC by-sa may require the name of the author as desired by the author, the title of the work and a link to the licence text), so double- (and triple-)check the licence conditions.

Have a look at other publications in your field and how they normally handle citations of images. Maybe they include the citations in a list of figures, maybe not.

Comment: Thanks! That's awesome, excactly what I was looking for.

Comment: But why are you using \parencite and not \cite? Also, the biblatex-examples.bib includes your reference in this example right?

Comment: @AntonNeundorfer I used `\parencite` purely for aesthetic reasons in this case. If I had written "A duck, picture adapted from " I would probably have used `\cite` and not `\parencite`. There is a lot of leeway as to how a citation like this could look like, so there are going to be many, many variations of a common theme. Just pick something you like or have a look at examples in your field. If you still feel unsure ask your advisor.

Comment: Yes, `biblatex-examples.bib` includes `sigfridsson` and many more example entries. I use that file because it should be available on all machines where `biblatex` is installed and it allows me to save on the typing.